# Sequelize query to count and update a data if count value returns 1

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am building a register system in my nodejs application.
I am using Sequelize js as ORM.
This is my controller

```
exports.activateaccount=function(req,res,next){
var token=req.params.token;
indexmodel.activateemail(token,function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
    else{
        res.send('Activation Completed');
    }
})
 }
```

i am taking token and sending it to model as :

```
exports.activateemail=function(token,callback){
partner.count({where:{token:token}}).then((partner)=>{
    Sequelize.query("UPDATE partners WHERE token='"+token+"' SET confirmed=1").then(partner=>{
        callback();
    })
})
  }
```

I want to set '**confirmed**' column of that '**token**' as 1 if token matches.
Currently the default value is 0. 
Does anyone knows code of it.
I tried using Sequelize.query but it is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using raw query like :

```
Sequelize.query("UPDATE partners WHERE token='"+token+"' SET confirmed=1")
```

You should be using the Sequelize way , this way you can handle it better.

By better means :

1. In future you can switch to any dialect
2. you can use hooks
3. And others ...

But with method you have used you can't to do such things.

**Here you go :**

```
partner.update({ 'confirmed' : 1 },{ where : { 'token' : token , 'confirmed' : 0 }})
.then(...) // handle update
.catch(...); // handle error
```

**For delete :**

```
partner.destroy({ where : { 'token' : token , 'confirmed' : 1 }});
```

Comment: and can you tell me how to delete token record of same column after confirmed is 1

Comment: @Bibek , please check updated answer, have also added for delete.

Comment: thanks but I mean to say first check token if exist change confirmed=1 and empty the token record of same in single statement. Thanks Can you help with that?

Comment: .update will return no of records updated that you can check , if that is greated then 0 , means rows are updates and if its 0 then nothing to update. Please console log the .then after .update you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I got it. :) You save my hours